# Aggregate at either of two levels

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau, I am joining two tables where a header can have multiple details
Work Order Header
Work Order Details

The joined data looks like this:
Header.ID | Header.ManualTotal | Details.ID | Details.LineTotal
A | 1000 | 1 | 550
A | 1000 | 2 | 35
A | 1000 | 3 | 100
B | 335 | 1 | 250
B | 335 | 2 | 300
C | null | 1 | 50
C | null | 2 | 25
C | null | 3 | 5
C | null | 4 | 5

Where there is a manual total, use that, if there is no manual total, use the sum of the line totals
ID | Total
A | 1000
B | 335
C | 85

I tried something like this:
`ifnull( sum({fixed [Header ID] : [Manual Total] }), sum([Line Total]) )`

basically I need to use the `ifnull`, then use the manual total if it exists, or sum line totals if it doesn't

Please advise on how to use LODs or some other solution to get the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not require a level-of-detail calculation.

Just try this:

- use an `inner join` on `id` of the two tables
- create this calculation: `ifnull(median([Manual Total]),sum([Line Total]))`
- insert `agg(your_calculation)` into your sheet